# Is there a way to evaluate for 0's in between 1's in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that looks like this:

| 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Trying to evaluate concurrent 1's (where no interruption in sequence). So output should look like:

| 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | Concurrent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | True |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | False |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | False |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | True |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | False |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | False |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | False |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | False |

Is there a way to evaluate rows where if a 1 is followed by 0 then false else True?

Comment: yes normally that would be the case, in this instance we are looking for recurring 1's but where 'breaks' occur, so all 0's was the row example to provide a scope that there is no value to keep for this evaluation

Comment: basically i'm trying to find cases where after 1 a 0 occurs

Comment: Even though there are 5 answers, some are 2 or 3 answers in one submission. If there is a badge for `questions with the most answers`, you may be on your way to earning it.  ;-)

Comment: Definitely the question should be upvoted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you feel about using VBA, but here's a solution.

First, we check to see if the final cell is a 0. If it is, then we automatically assume false:

```vba
If .Cells(.Cells.Count) = 0 Then Exit Function
```

Next, we will loop through each cell in the range, checking the current cell against the next cell. But before we do this, we do some pre-checks to ensure that the numbers are 'legal' (as in, they must be a `0` or a `1`. Since I have the function returning a `Boolean` value, you will actually receive a `#VALUE!` error instead of the one I used (`xlErrNum`), but it doesn't break anything.

The loop is designed to grab all the `False` scenarios, so therefore if it passes the loop, it will return a true value.

Add this code to a VBA module:

```vba
Public Function TestForBreakage(rng As Range) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long
    With rng
        If .Cells(.Cells.Count) = 0 Then Exit Function              'Can't end w/ a 0
        For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
            If .Cells(i).Value < 0 Or .Cells(i).Value > 1 Then      '# other than 0 or 1 used
                TestForBreakage = CVErr(xlErrNum)
                Exit Function
            ElseIf .Cells(i).Value <> Int(.Cells(i).Value) Then     'Decimal used
                TestForBreakage = CVErr(xlErrNum)
                Exit Function
            End If
            If i = .Cells.Count Then Exit For
            If .Cells(i).Value > .Cells(i + 1).Value Then Exit Function 'Returns False
        Next i
    End With
    TestForBreakage = True  'If made through the loop unscathed then must be True

End Function
```

---

Since this didn't originate as a VBA question, just in case you are unfamiliar with VBA I will provide the steps to add the above code.

1. Save your workbook as a **Macro-Enabled Workbook**
   [image]
2. Simultaneously press <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> inside your workbook. This brings up the VBA Editor.
3. Head to `Insert` then `Module`
   [image]
4. Paste the above code into the new module you just created
   [image]
5. Close the editor
6. Use the **newly-created formula** that we just made
   [image]

Comment: This is the best solution, thank you. Is there a way to count the number of times that a 1 is followed by 0? (number of gaps per row?)

Comment: So `0111`, `0001`, and `1111` would be 0... `1011` would be 1... `1000` would be either 1 or 3... `1010` would be 2? Need clarification on the `1000` and confirmation if others are correct. I have a feeling that a new question would be preferable as I am not sure if it would be easily answered in a comment with limited character count / formatting. Or at least we can visit in one of [SO's chats](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Apologies for the delay, 1000, would be just '1' in this context, 10111, is '1', and 1010 would be '2'

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a spill formula in Excel 365:

```
=LET(concat,A2:A9&B2:B9&C2:C9&D2:D9,
ISERROR(FIND("10",concat))*ISNUMBER(FIND("1",concat))=1)
```

(this is only practical for a small number of columns)

[image]

---

The non-spill, non-let version would be:

```
=AND(ISERROR(FIND("10",TEXTJOIN("",,A2:D2))),ISNUMBER(FIND("1",TEXTJOIN("",,A2:D2))))
```

and this could be expanded to several columns.

Comment: Very clever - not immediately obvious to me that you only have to check the last column for a 1 until I thought about it. I quite like my non-spill because it should cover the case where you could have a space between 1's and 0's if that were ever needed . I liked your xlookup that you put in as a comment as well.

Comment: I removed that comment since I believe the matrix would be filled with 1's and 0's and therefor your `CONCAT()` approach is more pleasing to the eye for me =).

Answer (score 4):

Hereby another alternative for Excel2019 or higher:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=ISERROR(FIND(0,CONCAT(A2:D2)*1))
```

Or:

```
=ISERROR(FIND(0,--CONCAT(A2:D2)))
```

And with Microsoft365, you could opt to spill an array directly through:

```
=ISERROR(FIND(0,--MID(CONCAT(A2:D9),SEQUENCE(8,,,4),4)))
```

Or, if available:

```
=BYROW(A2:D10,LAMBDA(x,ISERROR(FIND(0,--CONCAT(x)))))
```

---

For previous versions of Excel I'd go with the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384728/9758194).

Comment: OMG!!! - Again, the smallest formula in the world and completely lateral. Well done!

Comment: Thanks @markfitzpatrick, but it wasn't untill I say the answer by Tom untill I realized how we could utilize concatenation =). Communal strength!

Answer (score 2):

Use `COUNTIFS` with offset ranges.

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:C2,1,B2:D2,0)=0
```

[image]

If the row must contain at least one 1, then perhaps:

```
=AND(COUNTIFS(A2:D2,1),COUNTIFS(A2:C2,1,B2:D2,0)=0)
```

[image]

Comment: in the first example there is a false positive in the 3rd row for result, i currently have the second one in use but was wondering if there is a perhaps a formula that can evaluate the entire row at once? I wish power bi DAX was applicable here...(I can't because it's in excel)

Comment: The second formula can definitely be expanded to more columns.

Comment: so would it all be wrapped by an IF to work in the manner I need?

Comment: Seems the answer to me...

Comment: The 2nd option can be written as `=AND(D2,COUNTIFS(A2:B2,1,B2:C2,0)=0)` =)

Comment: @JvdV yes, very cute :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the logic is that the ones are unbroken from 2021 backwards, then another approach would be:

```
=AND(D2,SUM( --(FREQUENCY( IF(A2:D2,COLUMN(A2:D2)), IF(A2:D2,0,COLUMN(A2:D2)))>0) )=1)
```

Where 2021 is in column D. It looks for streaks of 1's starting from column D. If there are none or there is more than 1, it is false.

[image]